# Conditions for the identity to be true

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm writing an article about some useful techniques of integration. In the article I make use of the following ( well known ) identities.Here $p$ is a polynomial:

$$\int_{a}^{b} p(x)\cot x \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b} p(x)\sin 2nx \, \mathrm{d} x \tag{1}$$

$$\int_{a}^{b} p(x) \csc x \, \mathrm{d}x= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin (2n+1)x \, \mathrm{d}x  \tag{2}$$

$$\int_{a}^{b} p(x) \tan x \, \mathrm{d}x \overset{(?)}{=} -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin 2nx \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{3}$$

*I'm not sure about the 3rd one if the index of summation starts at 1 or 0. *

The proof of $(2)$ for instance comes from the fact that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \sin (2n+1)x  = \frac{\csc x}{2} - \frac{\cos (2N+1) x }{2 \sin x}$$

in combination with the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Now, the question is what are the conditions for the above $3$ identities to hold? Can we generalize for an arbitrary $f$? If so, what must $f$ satisfy for the identities to hold? twice differentiable , bounded , only integrable , etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

> Let $p:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial such that $p(a)=0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow b^-} p(x) \csc x = \ell \in \mathbb{R}$.  It holds that
> $$\int_{a}^{b} p(x) \csc x \, \mathrm{d}x= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin (2n+1)x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

*Proof:*  We start from the well known identity

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N} \sin (2n+1)x = \frac{\csc x}{2} - \frac{\cos (2N+1)x}{2 \sin x}$$

Integrating we have

$$2 \sum_{n=0}^{N} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin (2n+1) x \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \csc(x) \, \mathrm{d}x -\int_{a}^{b} p(x) \cdot \frac{\cos (2N+1)x}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Now let $N \rightarrow +\infty$. Using the Riemann - Lebesgue Lemma we have that

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \cdot \frac{\cos (2N+1)x}{\sin x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 0 $$

Hence,

$$\int_{a}^{b} p(x) \csc x \, \mathrm{d}x= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin (2n+1)x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Other similar identities are:

- $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} p(x)\cot x \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b} p(x)\sin 2nx \, \mathrm{d} x$
- $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \tan x \, \mathrm{d}x = -2
     \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \int_{a}^{b} p(x) \sin 2nx \,
     \mathrm{d}x$